# How to hide app layout until postexecute

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Ok I'm executing two async tasks as soon as I open my app. Currently have a Progress dialog but you can still see the layout in the background.
So the obvious answer would be to not `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` until the progress dialog is dismissed. But I can't do that as my first async task assigns a video into a view In its post execute and this throws a null pointer exception if the layout has not been set earlier.

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //video is a string file created by doinbackground
        card = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        card.setVideoPath(video);



        //Video Loop
        card.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
        card.start();



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the layout inside the code and use setVisibity()
For example you have to hide a linear layout with id myLayout
1) Set the id in layout xml

```
android:id="@+id/mylayout"
```

2)Now under OnCreate method in your code

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewbyId(R.id.mylayout);
linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

3) user postExecute method

```
linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Worked perfectly, thanks.